# Need a way to disable HTML Frame on request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 html pages. main.html, page1.html and page2.html. I am displaying page1.html, page2.html in main.html using following code.

**main.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="myjs.js"></script>
   </head>
    <iframe id="page_1" src="page1.html"></iframe>
    <iframe id="page_2" src="page2.html"></iframe>
</html>
```

**page1.html**

```
<html>
   <body>
         <table id="resultDetails">
               <th>Result Details</th>
               <tr>
                  <td>Row 1</td>
                  <div id="r1">
                       <p> R1 data</p>
                  </div>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>Row 2</td>
                  <div id="r2">                    
                  </div>
               </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**page2.html**

```
<html>
   <body>
         <div id="myDiv">
              <p> Testing.... </p>
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**myjs.js**

```
$(window).on('load',function () {
    $('#page_1').contents().bind('click','tr', function () {
        $('#page_2').contents().find('#myDiv').html($('#page_1').contents().find('#r1').html())
    }); 
});
```

On clicking on Row 1 of page1, the content of div id = "r1" will be displayed in page2. This works with no issues.

Issue: When there is no data available for specific row (say div id= "r2"), then i want to hide the frame of page2.  How we can achieve this?

Any thoughts

Comment: I would say avoid using iframe, you will be dealing with IE problems and cache issue, this thing can be done very easily with `jQuery` or best go with `Angular`

Comment: Not entirely clear what the hide/show rules are

Comment: I just want to code or procedure to hide the frame

Answer (score 0):

My thought on this:

Take an id for the row which you are trying to access. Before showing the data check whether there is data present or not using

```
$("trid").innerhtml=''
```

and then perform your action.
Hope it helps.

Comment: code is invalid and even if it wasn't it doesn't answer the question